# Django adminsite customize search_fields query

Tags: python, django, django-admin

In the django admin you can set the search_fields for the ModelAdmin to be able to search over the properties given there. My model class has a property that is not a real model property, means it is not within the database table. The property relates to another database table that is not tied to the current model through relations.
But I want to be able to search over it, so I have to somehow customize the query the admin site creates to do the filtering when the search field was filled - is this possible and if, how?
I can query the database table of my custom property and it then returns the ids of the model classes fitting the search. This then, as I said, has to flow into the admin site search query.

Thanks!

Answer (score 32):

Since django 1.6, you can customize the search by defining a `get_search_results` method in your `ModelAdmin` subclass.

It is well explained in [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_search_results). The following example is copied from this doc.

```
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'age')
    search_fields = ('name',)

    def get_search_results(self, request, queryset, search_term):
        queryset, use_distinct = super(PersonAdmin, self).get_search_results(request, queryset, search_term)
        try:
            search_term_as_int = int(search_term)
            queryset |= self.model.objects.filter(age=search_term_as_int)
        except:
            pass
        return queryset, use_distinct
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use `search_fields = ['foreign_key__related_fieldname']`
like `search_fields = ['user__email']` in the admin class that extends admin.ModelAdmin

read more [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.search_fields)

Comment: this suffers the same issue of @shahjapan 's answer

Answer (score -2):

this might can help

search_fields = ['foreign_key__related_fieldname']

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.search_fields

Comment: Well, as I said, the model class is not tied to the other model so there is no foreign key. Therefore this does not work.